# Adding UID attributes to my XAML file

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, localization, msbuild

I understood that I had to use `/t:updateuid`  to revise my XAML file.

[image: MSBuild]

I adjusted my project as indicated and it made no difference. My XAML file remains the same.

What have I done wrong?

As per the suggestion I tried using the Developer Command Prompt instead:

[image: Command Prompt results]

For some reason that fails too.

OK, so I have to use this command on the actual CSPROJ file (as indicated in the comments):

[image: New Results]

So the right command is `msbuild file.csproj /t:updateuid`

Is it standard practice to make this part of the general building of the application? I appreciate this is a side question.

Comment: Check the output window for results. And/or run MsBuild from a developer command prompt. There must be an error message somewhere.

Comment: @HenkHolterman OK, will look. Am I right though? I should be running this routine on the actual XAML file ...

Comment: A pity you let the actual command scroll out of range. I think you should use the the csproj file as target.

Comment: Using the developer command prompt, and using the csproj file was the way to go. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated to me in the comments, I should have been using the CSPROJ file and not the XAML file with the `msbuild` command.

Putting this in the **Post Build Event** did the trick:

```
echo Updating localization Uids
"$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe" "$(ProjectPath)" /t:updateuid
```